# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _StoreAction found - python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

In my script I am trying to take in variables through the command line using argparse. The first variable is a direcotry name. The second is a string using in a split method later. I've set them both up as str type. Here is my input:

`$ python ppB.py -CDFd ~/git/Bootils/xap -NS /xap/`

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ppB.py", line 338, in <module>
    main()
  File "ppB.py", line 312, in main
    list_of_cdffiles, names = glob(glob_pattern='*.cdf', directoryname=dirc, splitPattern=sp)
  File "ppB.py", line 34, in glob
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directoryname):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 278, in walk
    names = listdir(top)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, _StoreAction found
```

Here is my script

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    dirc = parser.add_argument("-CDFd",
                               nargs="?",
                               type=str,
                               default=".",
                               help="CDF Directory: Location of .cdf files to be processed \n")
    sp = parser.add_argument("-NS",
                             nargs="?",
                             type=str,
                             default=".",
                             help="Name Split: Where to split .cdf file name \n")
```

Additionally, this is the glob method where the problem originated:

```
def glob(glob_pattern, directoryname, splitPattern):
    '''
    Walks through a directory and its subdirectories looking for files matching
    the glob_pattern and returns a list=[].

    :param directoryname: Any accessible folder name on the filesystem.
    :param glob_pattern: A string like "*.txt", which would find all text files.
    :return: A list=[] of absolute filepaths matching the glob pattern.
    -Written by Lon Blauvelt 
    '''
    matches = []
    names = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directoryname):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, glob_pattern):
            absolute_filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            matches.append(absolute_filepath)

            name = filename.rsplit(splitPattern)[-1]
            names.append(name)

    print('n1', names)
    return matches, names
```

Am I setting a variable up incorrectly, is there an argument/parameter I am missing in the parser.add_argument() setup? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way you use `argparse` is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(....)
...
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)    # good debugging step
# args is a Namespace with attributes whose name is set in the add_arguments

glob(glob_pattern='*.cdf', directoryname=args.CDFd, splitPattern=args.NS)
```

Your `dirc` and `sp` variables are the `Action` (subclass) objects created and used by the `parser`.  They may be used when refining the parser setup, but otherwise they aren't useful after parsing.  The results of parsing are in the `args` Namespace created by `parse_args`.